# MVC How to load a view and a partial view from one controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a controller that returns a view that has a table in that view that's populated with information about orders

```
public class HomeController : Controller 
{
        public IActionResult OrderTracking()
        {
            List<WebOrder> orderList = SuperDAL.GetWebOrders();
            foreach(WebOrder order in orderList)
            {
                order.Parts = SuperDAL.GetPartsForWebOrder(order.ID);
            }

            return View(orderList);
        }
}
```

**OrderTracking View**

```
@model List<WebOrder>

        <table id="orderTable" class="orderTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Priority</th>
                    <th>Web Order Number</th>
                    <th>Order Number</th>
                    <th>Company</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                    <th>Due Date</th>
                    <th>Date Received</th>
                    <th>Customer</th>
                    <th>Order Cost</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var webOrder in Model)
                {
                    <tr data-ID="@webOrder.ID">
                        @*The tds with data-date are storing the date contained
                            within the tds in ISO date format. This value is
                            being pulled in JavaScript to avoid having
                            messy string formating in JS for date comparisons*@
                        <td class="@webOrder.getPriority().ToLower()">@webOrder.getPriority()</td>
                        <td>@webOrder.WebOrderNumber</td>
                        <td>@webOrder.ExternalOrderNumber</td>
                        <td>@webOrder.CompanyName</td>
                        <td>@webOrder.getOverallStatus()</td>
                        <td data-date="@webOrder.dueDateISOFormat()">@webOrder.getDueDate()</td>
                        <td data-date="@webOrder.dateReceivedISOFormat()">@webOrder.DateReceived</td>
                        <td>@webOrder.CustomerName</td>
                        <td>@webOrder.OrderCost</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
    @*The Order Modal*@
    <div id="orderModal" class="modal">
        @*Modal Content*@
    </div>
```

Each row in the table has a click event handler that when fired will send an ajax call to a controller to return a partial view with detailed information about the order.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/WebOrder/Details/",
            data: { 'id': orderID },
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (response) {

                $("#orderModal").html(response);

                //modal.style.display = "block";
                //Does more stuff

            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
```

```
public class WebOrderController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Details(int id)
        {
            WebOrder webOrder = SuperDAL.GetWebOrder(id);
            webOrder.Parts = SuperDAL.GetPartsForWebOrder(webOrder.ID);
            return PartialView("ModalPartial", webOrder);
        }

    }
```

The partial view returned from the `Details` controller is put in the `orderModal` div in the `OrderTracking` view.

By default, in my CSS I have that div hidden. When a row is clicked in the table, in the success part of the ajax call I unhide the div which is styled as a modal that pops up over the current page displaying more information about the order that was selected. The success section also applies other events to the modal.

Now the problem I'm trying to tackle is I would like to be able to display the modal with the partial view by just navigating in the URL bar to the `OrderTracking` controller and have it pull up the `OrderTracking` View as well as the modal and partial view. The URL would be something along the lines of domain/Home/OrderTracking/5 , where 5 would be the id of the order.

The reason for this is the end goal is to be able to have a qr code that will pull up an order when scanned by a qr reader, so the qr code would contain the url with the order number.

At the moment I'm having a hard time trying to conceptualize how I would achieve this. There are a few ways I have thought about being able to accomplish this by I don't believe they are right.

One way I thought about achieving this is to have an overloaded `OrderTracking` controller that uses a `GET` request. That controller will call the `Details` controller as well as returning the `OrderTracking` view, but while possibly do-able it most likely isn't the correct way to do it.

Another issue is that with the URL approach I cant fire off jQuery or JavaScript from the controller like I can in the ajax call that sets event handlers and other things. One way I though about dealing with this is to include a $(document).ready function in the partial view.

Let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to pass the orderID to your View and trigger the click event of the respective order in the table. This will trigger your post request and show the modal with the Partial View. i.e

Create a ViewModel:

```
public class OrderViewModel{
   public int? OrderID { get; set; }
   public List<WebOrder> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Change your Action:

```
public class HomeController : Controller 
{
        public IActionResult OrderTracking(int? orderID)
        {
            List<WebOrder> orderList = SuperDAL.GetWebOrders();
            foreach(WebOrder order in orderList)
            {
                order.Parts = SuperDAL.GetPartsForWebOrder(order.ID);
            }

            return View(new OrderViewModel(){ OrderID = orderID, Orders = orderList});
        }
}
```

Trigger click event:

```
<script>
   $(function(){
       if(@Model.OrderID !=null){
           //trigger click event
       }
   })
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do so,you can add the partial view directly in the View,And like `Siddanth` says,pass OrderId to your view.So that you even don't need click button to add the partial view.You can change like this:
OrderModel:

```
public class OrderModel
    {
        public WebOrder SelectedOrder { get; set; }
        public List<WebOrder> Orders { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult OrderTracking(int? orderId)
    {
        OrderModel orderModel = new OrderModel();
        List<WebOrder> orderList = SuperDAL.GetWebOrders();
        foreach (WebOrder order in orderList)
        {
            order.Parts = SuperDAL.GetPartsForWebOrder(order.ID);
        }
        orderModel.Orders = orderList;
        orderModel.SelectedOrder = new WebOrder();
        if (orderId != null)
        {
            WebOrder webOrder = SuperDAL.GetWebOrder(id);
            orderModel.SelectedOrder = webOrder;
            
        }
        return View(orderModel);
    }
```

change Web

---

Order:

```
public int? ID { get; set; }
```

View:

```
<div id="orderModal" class="modal" >
    @await Html.PartialAsync("ModalPartial", @Model)
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            if (@Model.SelectedOrder.ID!=null) {
                $("#orderModal").modal("show");
            }
        })
    </script>
```